# Automatically split takes into individual files in Final Cut Pro

Tags: video, premiere, final-cut-pro

One of my 'favourite' features in Adobe Premiere Pro CS family is [automatic scene detection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/PremierePro/4.0/WS1c9bc5c2e465a58a91cf0b1038518aef7-7f9fa.html) - its  ability to spit out individual clips when capturing from tape using pause/stop information. As far as I know, Final Cut Pro has no automnatic way of doing this. Splitting clips during import manually is so tedious. Is there something I'm missing out, or a plugin perhaps that provides this feature in FCP 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a  pop-up menu in the General tab in User Preferences that has all the options in dealing with timecode breaks. There is an option where you choose Make New Clip from the “On timecode break”. This option will make a new clip in the bin when a timecode break is reached.

SRC: [http://documentation.apple.com/en/finalcutpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=20%26section=5%26tasks=true](http://documentation.apple.com/en/finalcutpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=20&section=5&tasks=true)

Comment: I clarified the intent of my question for what specific feature I'm looking an analogous option for. The timecode break option is for a different purpose, it seems.

Comment: In Final Cut a timecode break is when the tape is stopped. So then a break in the timecode is detected (indicating there was a stopping of the recording), final cut will create a new clip in the browser. And this will all be done when capturing from a camera/tapedeck via firewire. I am pretty sure that this is what your looking for

Comment: There will be no timecode breaks between scenes if you are in rec-run mode (which you should be if you plan to batch capture) thus there will be no splitting. You should use the DV Start/Stop Detect feature in the Mark menu.

Answer (score 3):

Select the clip you wish to work on in the browser, then in the top menu bar for FCP, select Mark > DV Start/Stop Detect. This will break the clip up by the start/stop metadata generated when you were shooting.

The options in the user preferences are for timecode breaks that occur during capture.

ps: I don't know when this DV Start/Stop Detect feature was first included, but it was in FCP3 in 2002...